# set x range in seaborne violinplot by month

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I am trying to plot temperature data recorded over the year using a seaborn violinplot.

I manage to do the following plot:

[image: Seaborn violinplor from march to december]

I would like to start the plot in January, even if the data collection starts in March for 2021, in order to display yearly plots on top of each other and be able to visually compare same months of different years.

I tried the following use of `set_xlim`, but it didn't work

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(24,10))
fontsize=18
ax.set_xlim(1,12)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=fontsize) 
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=fontsize) 

plt.rcParams['font.size']=24

seaborn.violinplot(x = weather21_2h.index.month, y = weather21_2h['T out_x'], ax=ax, palette="GnBu",inner = "box")
plt.title('Statistique des températures par mois 2021')
plt.xlabel('Mois', fontsize=24)
plt.ylabel('Températures (°C)')

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Is there a way ?

Comment: You could use `sns.violinplot(..., order=range(1, 13))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass `order` parameter to [**`saeborn.violinplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(24,10))
fontsize=18

plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=fontsize)
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=fontsize)

plt.rcParams['font.size']=24

sns.violinplot(x = weather21_2h.index.month,
               y = weather21_2h['T out_x'],
               ax=ax,
               palette="GnBu",
               inner = "box",
               order = range(1, 13))

ax.set_title('Statistique des températures par mois 2021')
ax.set_xlabel('Mois', fontsize=24)
ax.set_ylabel('Températures (°C)')

ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, so simple and I didn't see that!